# Empty request parameters in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, php-8.2

I have a strange problem with my project in Laravel 10.  My `$request` comes empty in my controller.

**Controller**

```
public function postSettings(Request $request){
    $user = $request->user();
    $request = $request->validate([
        'scroll_lock' => 'boolean',
        'test_mode' => 'boolean',
    ]);
    $settings =  Settings::find($user->id) ? Settings::where('user_id', $user->id)->first() :  new Settings();
    $settings->scroll_lock = $request['scroll_lock'];
    $settings->test_mode = $request['test_mode'];
    $settings->save();
    return route('get-settings');
}
```

**Middleware**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{

    $user = Auth::user();
    if( $user->user_type == UserType::Manager || $user->user_type == UserType::Operator ) {
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::QUESTIONS);
    }
    else {
        return $next( $request );
    }
```

**Form**

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('post-settings') }}">
        @csrf
        <div id=""  class="my-4">
            <div class="activity card" style="--delay: .2s">
                <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="question-title text-justify">Settings</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="answers-container h-100">
                    <div class="align-content-center">
                        <div class="m-3 row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="scroll-lock" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" @if($dataview->settings->scroll_lock)value="1" checked @else value="0" @endif>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Disabilita blocco scroll nel questionario.</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="test-mode" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" @if($dataview->settings->test_mode)value="1" checked @else value="0" @endif>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Abilita la modalità di test</label>
                                    <p>Invio email disabilitato, questionario ridotto.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="my-3 row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md next">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/settings', [DashboardController::class, 'getSettings'] )->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'switchUserType'])->name('get-settings');

Route::post('/settings', [DashboardController::class, 'postSettings'] )->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'switchUserType'])->name('post-settings');
```

The request class is `use Illuminate\Http\Request`; I already have double-checked with `dd($request)` and Xdebug, but both come with empty parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: are you being redirected by the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You're using different names for form fields in your HTML and Laravel code. For example, in HTML you're using scroll-lock and test-mode, but in Laravel you're using scroll_lock and test_mode.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="scroll_lock" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckScrollLock" @if($dataview->settings->scroll_lock) value="1" checked @else value="0" @endif>
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="test_mode" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckTestMode" @if($dataview->settings->test_mode) value="1" checked @else value="0" @endif>
```

To avoid overwriting the original $request, assign the validated data to a different variable. Here's the corrected code:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'scroll_lock' => 'Boolean',
    'test_mode' => 'Boolean',
]);
```

Comment: Already did, nope unfortunately.

Comment: @LucaScandroglio Did this resolve your problem?

Comment: Hi, not yet, but i had understood that there is a problem with the blade template.